# Delay in HTML rendering - Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.6

I'm using `laravel 5.6`.

When I navigate from one page to another, the page navigates properly but the `HTML` gets rendered after an delay of 0.5-1 sec on `Chrome`; this delay is almost double on `Firefox`.

I have no computation that happens in the blade files. All the computation is done in the controller and sent to the blade file to render.

Ideally the `HTML` should render once the response is received by the browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add your code aswell as some screenshots of your Chrome Developer Tools under the network tab.

Comment: You could use chrome DevTools (right mouse-click -> inspect element) and go to the tab "network". Then refresh te page and see whats happening there.